# How do I write data to a file that I have taken from an SQL database in Python? (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, database, object, sqlite

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Forename =:forename AND Surname =:surname AND YearGroup =:yeargroup AND FormNumber =:formnumber BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate", {"forename": forename, "surname": surname, "yeargroup": yeargroup, "formnumber": formnumber, "startdate": startdate, "enddate": enddate})

studentRequest = c.fetchall()
records = studentRequest

#write to file

f = open('Student Report', 'w')
f.write(name)
f.write(' Form Number: ' + (yeargroup +'/'+ formnumber))
f.write(str(records))
f.close()
```

This is my code but it doesn't seem to write the data from the database to the file. The name, Forum Number etc is written though.

Can anyone help?

Comment: try printing out 'records' to the terminal.  I'm guessing it is a list or a tuple so you would need to access individual records by iterating through it. for item in record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your output have "[]" in it? It sounds like your query doesn't find any matches.

If this isn't so, prepare a [complete, **runnable**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example showing the problem.

Comment: Yes it does return a [] when attempted. Maybe this is a problem with inputting data to the database then?

Comment: I think your problem is your query syntax.  Try starting with a small piece of it and see if that returns anything.  Then build it from there.

Comment: @Jambofun, Yes, or your select query isn't the one you really want. A very common error people make when adding data to a database is forgetting to commit.

Comment: I think that I may of found the issue thank you Bill. However, i'm learning as I'm programming so am unsure of how to tackle it. I believe its to do with the 'BETWEEN' in my query as I have not related it in any way to the Date column in my table. How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps the query you're looking for is more like `SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Forename =:forename AND Surname =:surname AND YearGroup =:yeargroup AND FormNumber =:formnumber AND Date BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate`?

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you all so much. I will now work on formatting the text document.